# Squid only cache content for a specific domain and file type.

Tags: caching, squid

I want to setup Squid to cache specific files (.jpeg) from a specific domain. These files are updated daily. I'm running Ubuntu. I have a script on my laptop that makes use of these files and ideally I would like this script to make calls to the Squid cache instead of directly to the server. I don't want to cache content that is not from the domain and is not of the correct file type. Is this possible, and what do I need to edit in `squid.conf` ?

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solution:

```
acl filecachetype urlpath_regex \.jpeg
acl cacheDomain dstdomain <your domainname> or acl cacheDomain dst <domain ip>
cache deny !filecachetype !cacheDomain
```

Will not work. ACLs do AND on the same like so it means that it will only avoid caching when a file is both non-jpeg and not on domain.com. It will still cache:

- all files on <your domain>
- all jpeg files on any domain

What you need is:

```
acl filecachetype urlpath_regex \.jpeg
acl cacheDomain dstdomain <your domainname>
cache deny !filecachetype
cache deny !cacheDomain
```

This will deny caching files that are not jpeg (no matter where they are, even on your server) and also will deny caching files not on <your domain> (even if they are jpeg). Logical OR, instead of AND.

Answer (score 1):

```
acl filecachetype urlpath_regex \.jpeg
acl cacheDomain dstdomain <your domainname> or acl cacheDomain dst <domain ip>
cache deny !filecachetype !cacheDomain 
cache all
```

Comment: or else you can just configure squid in reverse proxy mode to cache the file of webserver/domain which is hosting the jpeg files that you are looking for